# Keep chat history with socket.io-redis

Tags: redis, socket.io, store

I have chat with socket.io and redis as store. My question is, how can i retrieve all emits from socket room? Chat is working, just on refresh all messages lost. Below is how i manage redis store.

```
var redis = require('redis').createClient;
var adapter = require('socket.io-redis');
var pub = redis(port, host, {});
var sub = redis(port, host, { detect_buffers: true});
io.adapter(adapter({ pubClient: pub, subClient: sub }));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-bluemix-html5chat/index.html those article solve this problem. Step 4 contain the answer. Code:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var redisClient = redis.createClient(port, host);
redisClient.lpush('messages', JSON.stringify(data)); // push into redis
redisClient.lrange('messages', 0, 99, function(err, reply) {
  //reply contains all messages
});
```